# How to call a Rails Mountable Engine method from a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Mountable Engine Controller Method:

```
module ServiceApi
  module Api
    module V1
      class RequestorController < ApplicationController
        def get_details(query_parameters)
          #some code here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails app Controller Calling the `get_details(params)` method from the Mountable Engine

```
ServiceApi::Api::V1::RequestorController.new.get_details(params)
```

Comment: Is this the right way to call the method from the engine ?

Comment: Why do you want to call engine controller's action outside? What is the scenario?

Comment: I an making some calls to an api via the engine, so I need to call the engines controller action from my rails application where the engine is mounted. So in order to call the engine actions in the rails application I am using the above syntax which fetches me results , my questions is - is it the correct way of calling a method ?

Comment: It's a dirty solution. You should not call controller's actions like this

Comment: @RAJ ok if its a dirty solution, can you say/tell me how to call action(controller action to fetch the results of api). Better solution please

Comment: @Veeru This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522587/rails-model-to-call-controller-action

Comment: @RAJ The method that I am trying to call is in the Engines controller not Engines model , the engine (gem) is in a rails application and I want to call the engines controller methods from the rails application .

Comment: @FrancescaRodricks if it's mounted you should be able to inherit from that controller

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're not looking for a controller action, but rather a *helper method*. For instance, controller actions don't take parameters.

If you still want it to live in the controller as stated, that's fine, but you can extract it to a helper and include that helper in every controller you want to use it in.

For instance,

```
# [engine]/app/helpers/requestor_helper.rb

module ServiceApi::Api::V1::RequestorHelper
  def get_details(query_parameters)
    # code
  end
end
```

and then in your controller

```
include ServiceApi::Api::V1::RequestorHelper
```

No need to abuse classes when what you want is a [module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html).